# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined - chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have this simple html:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

and this js:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

Even though the canvas is configured with `myChart` id, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kroejrhx/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

After revisiting the question, here's your problem: you are using the wrong version of `chart.js`. According to [this section](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-selecting-the-correct-build), if you want to use an axis that's time based, you either need to explicitly include `moment.js`, or use the bundle version.

Changing the resource in your jsfiddle to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.bundle.min.js` will show the expected chart. No need to change the code at all.

Comment: 10x. Now i ain't getting any error, but still doesn't see the chart.

Comment: Thanks a lot this 2.1.4 version fixed `Cannot read property '_view' of undefined` issue of chartjs

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Chart.js v2.0 then this CDN will work.

[https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.bundle.min.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.bundle.min.js%22)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the version 2 of `chart.js`. If you are using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/), in your `package.json`, update chart.js e.g., **`"chart.js": "^2.1.1",`**. In case you use [react-chartjs-2](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2), you will still need to make sure that your [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) version is 2 or bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Use this : `var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");`

Instead of : `var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");`