# Display Bar Chart on Flask API using Chart.js

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, chart.js

I'm trying to display pie and bar chart using Flask API on html page using chart.js. I am able to display pie chart but bar chart is getting below error.
"cannot read property of undefined (reading 'offsetWidth')" under "/nutrition_analysis" route.

[image]

Please find below Python main.py code,

```
    
# importing the necessary dependencies
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import pandas as pd

from flask import send_file
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline
import logging


from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)  # initializing a flask app


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])  # route to display the home page
@cross_origin()
def homePage():
    return render_template("home.html")



@app.route('/form_fill',methods=['GET','POST'])  # route to display the home page
@cross_origin()

def form_fill():
    return render_template("form_fill.html")

@app.route('/download_file',methods=['GET','POST'])  # route to display the home page
@cross_origin()

def download_file():
    path = 'Daily Nutrition Requirement.xlsx'
    return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)


@app.route('/nutrition_analysis',methods=['POST','GET']) # route to show the predictions in a web UI
@cross_origin()
def nutrition_analysis():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            #  reading the inputs given by the user
            name = (request.form['name'])
            age = float(request.form['age'])
            weight = float(request.form['weight'])
            reference = (request.form['reference'])
            phone = float(request.form['phone'])
            emailid = (request.form['emailid'])

            file = request.form['customer_data']
            customer_data = pd.read_excel(file)

            RDA = pd.read_excel('Recommended_Nutrition.xlsx')

            df = pd.concat([RDA, customer_data], ignore_index=True)

            df_Carbs = df[df["Nutrients"] == "Carbohydrate"]
            df_Fat = df[df["Nutrients"] == "Fats"]
            df_Prot = df[df["Nutrients"] == "Proteins"]
            df_Fbr = df[df["Nutrients"] == "Fiber"]

            df_Macros = pd.concat([df_Carbs, df_Fat, df_Prot, df_Fbr])

            df_Macros_Exp = df_Macros[df_Macros["Category"] == "Exp"]
            # df_Macros_Obs = df_Macros[df_Macros["Category"] == "Obs"]


            # plt.pie(df_Macros_Exp["Value"], labels=df_Macros_Exp["Nutrients"], autopct='%1.1f%%')
            # plt.title("Expected Macros as per RDA", fontweight='bold')
            # plt.savefig('chart.png')

            values = df_Macros_Exp["Value"].tolist()
            labels = df_Macros_Exp["Nutrients"].tolist()
            colors = ["#F7464A", "#46BFBD", "#FDB45C", "#FEDCBA"]

            # Bar Chart

            df_stack = pd.merge(RDA,customer_data[['Nutrients','Value']],on='Nutrients', how='left')

            df_stack1=df_stack[['Nutrients','Value_x','Value_y']].copy()
            df_stack1["RDA"]=100
            df_stack1["Intake"]=((df_stack1["Value_y"] - df_stack1["Value_x"])/df_stack1["Value_x"])*100
            df_stack1.drop(["Value_x", "Value_y"], axis = 1, inplace = True)

            def color(x):
                if x < 0 or x > 50 :
                    return '#F7464A'
                else:
                    return '#46BFBD'

            df_stack1["Color"]=df_stack1["Intake"].apply(color)

            values_bar = df_stack1["Intake"].tolist()
            labels_bar = df_stack1["Nutrients"].tolist()
            colors_bar = df_stack1["Color"].tolist()


            #dt=datetime.now()
            
            # showing the prediction results in a UI
            return render_template('nutrition_analysis.html',s1=name,s2=age,s3=weight,s4=reference,s5=phone,s6=emailid,set=zip(values, labels, colors),set2=zip(values_bar,labels_bar,colors_bar))
        except Exception as e:
            print('The Exception message is: ',e)
            logging.debug(e)
            return 'something is wrong'
    # return render_template('results.html')
    else:
        return render_template('home.html')
        



if __name__ == "__main__":

    logging.basicConfig(filename='Nutrition_Analysis.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8001, debug=True)
    #app.run(debug=True) # running the app
```

Please find html page which need to be rendered below,

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Macro Analysis</title>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="item active" style="display: flex; height: 100px;">
   <div style=" width: 30%;">
      <h1><p>Liv365 Nutrition Analysis Report  :</p></h1>

      <br>name : {{s1}}</br>
      <br>age : {{s2}}</br>
      <br>weight : {{s3}}</br>
      <br>reference : {{s4}}</br>
      <br>phone : {{s5}}</br>
      <br>emailid : {{s6}}</br>

       </div>


        <div style=" width: 30%;">



    <h1>Macro Analysis</h1>

    <canvas id="chart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var pieData = [
        {% for values, labels, colors in set %}
          {
            value: {{values}},
            label: "{{labels}}",
            color : "{{colors}}"
          },
        {% endfor %}
      ];


      // draw pie chart
      new Chart(document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d")).Pie(pieData);

      </script>

    </div>
<div style=" width: 40%;">

    <h1>Micro Analysis</h1>

         <canvas id="bar" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var barData = [
        {% for values_bar, labels_bar, colors_bar in set2 %}
          {
            value: {{values_bar}},
            label: "{{labels_bar}}",
            color : "{{colors_bar}}"
          },
        {% endfor %}
      ];

       new Chart(document.getElementById("bar"), {
          type: 'bar',
          data: {
            labels: barData["label"],
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Population (millions)",
                backgroundColor: barData["color"],
                data: barData["value"]
              }
            ]
          },
          options: {
            legend: { display: false },
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Total Confirmed Cases of COVID in May'
            }
          }
      });

    </script>

</div>


</div>

   



</body>

</html>
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance!!!

Regards,
Rohan

Comment: Have you tried this version issue solution mentioned in this link [uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-undefined-chart-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575549/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-undefined-chart-js)

Comment: I tried with the above suggestions now even pie chart is not visible. So this issue is definitely with the version of chart.js used. Please suggest if you are able to resolve with any other version.

Comment: Opted for py-script and was able to display the charts